# PCLStorage FileSystem is only available in Android, not iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I'm writing a cross platform application in xamarin, for Android and iOS, and I need to save some text files to local storage. I'm using PCLstorage, but whenever I mouse over any PCLStorage code, it says "MyApplication.Android: available, MyApplication.iOS not available". How can I use PCLStorage to store files on both platforms? Or is there another way I can do this? Here's an example of some of my code:

```
public async Task CreateRealFileAsync(string filename, string filebody)
    {
        // get hold of the file system
        IFolder rootFolder = FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;

        // create a folder, if one does not exist already
        IFolder folder = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync("DadAppFiles", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

        // create a file, overwriting any existing file
        IFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        // populate the file with some text
        await file.WriteAllTextAsync(filebody);
    }
```

Comment: make sure you install nuget package on all platforms. I also assume that code you shown here is in PCL not in platform specific project.

Comment: @YuriS I installed the package using the command "Install-Package PCLStorage -Version 1.0.2". When I try and execute it again, it says it already exists in both projects. You're correct, the code is not in platform specific project.

Comment: have you tried to run it on both platforms? may be it's just intellisense bug? BTW, it should say it exists in 3 projects not 2. Check where it is installed using Nuget manager UI

Comment: I haven't been able to test it on iOS yet. When I use the Nuget UI, there are only 2 projects available to install to, MyApplication.Android and MyApplication.iOS. What is the 3rd it should exist in?

Comment: do you use PCL or shared project?

Comment: I'm using PCL. In visual studio I selected C# -> Cross-Platform -> PCL Xamarin.Forms when I set up the project.

Comment: Check where it is installed using Nuget manager UI. The third project is PCL

Comment: I tried removing and installing the PCLStorage package for iOS and that appears to have fixed it. Thank you for your help!